# Creating network for pgRouting from set of multiline strings?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a table which is a set of multiline strings.

I wish to create a pgrouting topology from that table so I can do shortest-path problems.

I have tried pgr_createTopology but it failed.

Is there a good tutorial on this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer to this question. It's not a tutorial, but it might be enough in your case: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116444/800