# Locate start point, end point intersecting line in a polyline

Tags: postgis, sql, line

I edit my question to be more clear. the last answers were not helpful for me, maybe I did not ask well my question.

I have a file of nodes and a file of polylines. In my file polylines, I have 2 fields, "NODEA" and "NODEB". In my node file, I have a unique "identifier" field for each node. I want to retrieve with a small line of code the identifier of the node at each end of my polyline.

I try this query but no results.

```
select id, 
       (select id_arret 
        from noeuds n 
        where st_within(st_startpoint(p.geometry), st_buffer(n.geometry, 1))) n_deb, 
       (select id_arret 
        from noeuds n 
        where st_within(st_endpoint(p.geometry), st_buffer(n.geometry, 1))) n_fin
from polylignes p;
```

---

"My purpose is to get for each line of the multiline the start and the end node of a line and to fill in 2 colomuns of my multiline table the good node."

Comment: Do you mean to say the polyline is in PostGIS?

Comment: yes the polyline is in postgis database

Comment: to clarify: you have two tables in PostGIS (let's call them 'node' and 'polyline')? what are the values of 'NODEA' and 'NODEB' in 'polyline', are those geometries or the same identifier (for example an ID number) as the 'identifier' in your 'node' table'? and does the 'node' table have geometries or is that a plain table with other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a geometry dump ('split' mulit geometries into their single parts) of your polyline first. Use `ST_StartPoint/ST_EndPoint` in conjunction with `ST_Dump`. A simple example:

```
SELECT ST_StartPoint(dmp.geom) AS sp,
       ST_EndPoint(dmp.geom) AS ep
FROM   <your_polyline_table>,
       LATERAL ST_Dump(<your_geometry_column>) AS dmp
;
```

---

**EDIT** (as above answer is useless after clarifying the question):

You cannot use `ST_StartPoint/ST_EndPoint` on *MULTILINESTRINGs*, these functions only work on *LINESTRING* geometries and that is supposedly why your query has no effect.

Getting the start/end point of a *MULTILINESTRING* unfortunately is no trivial task and a solution or workaround strongly depends on the actual topology of your *MULTILINESTRING*s.

There is the possibility that your *MULTILINESTRING*s can safely be convertet into *LINESTRING*s wich would make your task way easier. Try the steps mentioned in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116444/93656) post and update your question with the result (e.g. if your table has actual *MULTI* geometries or not). Or, in case your geometries can be converted to *LINESTRING*s, do that and run your query on these and see if you get any useful results.

Comment: okay, so now after you updated your question, this has become a completely different task and my answer has indeed no use for you as it is (@communitiy: do I delete the answer then?).

Comment: yes the answer is deleted. have you an idea for the answer to this question? thanks

Comment: your other question was deleted but I meant my own answer as it is useless ,) check my comment above and maybe provide some more details

Comment: i tried your query but get the geometry of the points. i'am not looking for the geometry of the points. my purpose is to get for each line of the multiline the start and the end node of a line and to fill in 2 colomuns of my multiline table the good node.  sorry for my english but i'm a french. tks

Answer (score 0):

The request was good

```
select id, (select id_arret from noeuds n where st_within(st_startpoint(p.geometry), st_buffer(n.geometry, 1))) n_deb, (select id_arret from noeuds n where st_within(st_endpoint(p.geometry), st_buffer(n.geometry, 1))) n_fin from polylignes p;
```

I followed the steps advised by https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/thingumabob and I get useful results.
I changed the multilinestring to linestring and it works very well.